# jQuery star rating plugin doesnt return correctly amount of stars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-bar-rating

I'm making a rating system to rate a post using 5 stars. I use the jQuery bar plugin for this ([jQuery bar plugin](https://antennaio.github.io/jquery-bar-rating/)).

Users can vote posts from 1 to 5. The data is stored in the database. After someone votes the stars will be disabled and show the amount of stars the user rated.

Rating is correctly stored in database and after user rate e.g. 3 stars It display 3 stars and `console.log` `currentRating` show correctly 3 stars, but when user go other page and go back to the post that rated it won't return the right amount and it will just show 1 star. When someone other user go that post that someone else rated it displays 1 star always.

So what I've done wrong or is barrating lib supposed work that way?

How I can always display right amount stars as active and when user come back or ctrl+f5 right amount stars displayed?

**Code:**

```
    $rating_res = "SELECT * FROM post_rating
                   WHERE post_id = " . $id . " AND userid = " . $userid;

    $rating_arr = sql_query($rating_res);
    $getRating = mysql_fetch_array($rating_arr);
    $rating = $getRating['rating'];

    $avg_res = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating), 1) as numRating 
               FROM post_rating WHERE post_id=".$id;

    $avgresult = sql_query($avg_res);
    $fetchAverage = mysql_fetch_array($avgresult);
    $numRating = $fetchAverage['numRating'];

    if ($numRating <= 0) {
        $numRating = "N/A";
    }

<select id='rating_<?php echo $id; ?>' name="star_rating_option" 
        class="rating" data-id='rating_<?php echo $id; ?>'>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    Rating: <span id='numeric_rating_<?php echo $id; ?>'><?php echo $numRating; ?></span>
```

**And here is jquery barrating part:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   currentRating = $(".rating").val();
   console.log(currentRating);

    $('#rating_<?php echo $id; ?>').barrating('set',<?php echo $rating; ?>);
});

$(function () {
    $('.rating').barrating({
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
        initialRating: $(this).data('current-rating'),
        //initialRating: currentRating,
        
        onSelect: function (value, text, event) {
            
            var el = this;
            var el_id = el.$elem.data('id');
            
            if (typeof (event) !== 'undefined') {
                var split_id = el_id.split("_");
                var post_id = split_id[1];
                $.ajax({
                    url: './rate.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        post_id: post_id,
                        rating: value
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var average = data['numRating'];
                        $('#numeric_rating_' + post_id).text(average);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: As jQuery exhibits quirky behaviour depending on which version is used, please upload a working version of your app, recreating the problem, to a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Few notes, `$(document).ready(function() {});` and `$(function () {});` are equivalents, so the order is wrong, you should first initialize the `barrating` and then doing `barrating('set', ...)`.

`$(".rating").val()` since you dont have any option as `selected` the value will be allways the same, could change if you correct the document.ready ordering, either way you cannot use it as per commented line `initialRating: currentRating` because that information doenst exist yet, its the barrating initialization which set it. Purpouse of `initialRating` is different then setting the current value btw.

`initialRating: $(this).data('current-rating'),` there is no attribute `data-current-rating` at the initialization, so this one is wrong too, imo you are missing that attribute.

`id` and `data-id` contains the same value its kinda nonsence, you could simply just put the id into data-id attribute and omit the string spliting part.

From your post its not clear how do you include the javascript part into your page, the initialization part should be in separate file to properly use caching and the setting part in php because you printing the current rating from php variable. Take a look at page source locate the line `$('#rating_<?php echo $id; ?>').barrating('set',<?php echo $rating; ?>);` and check if there is actually expected output, if there is then its just the ordering problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to change code same as many tutorials, but still after ctrl+f5 or go other page and then back to post page it show only 1 star active. It still show avg rating correctly = one rate - 4 stars.

I copy/paste this tutorial and same result: 

https://www.phpcodingstuff.com/blog/star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-php-and-mysql.html

https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/php-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-and-ajax